# Use element from response text in JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I do some logic to get file content.

I have SVG file and I need to read file in code

I do this by using `$.ajax()` function

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: shapes.svg,
    dataType: 'html'
}).then(function (value) {
   // HTML code from SVG file.
    console.log(value);
});
```

The problem starts here...
Now I have plain text and I need **document** in order to be able to use JS functions.

I need exactly **`getBBox()`**

So, I want to use something like **`document.createElment()`** but it only accepts HTML tag name not all element with its attributes.

below is part of the response from SVG file

```
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="2200" height="2200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgimportshapes" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-paper-data="&quot;unlocked&quot;" id="ShapeLayer" fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="none" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">
        <text x="1018.68119" y="511.99246" id="text" fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" font-family="helvetica" font-weight="normal" font-size="18" text-anchor="start">Parterre places debout</text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: please clarify, what do you  mean by "use"?  You have ajax response, that is SVG file contents, and what you need to do with it? display svg image on the page? insert this into $('#your_element').html(your_svg_contents) ?

Comment: You need to add it to DOM to get the bounding box. See my solution below using jQuery element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to DOM first in order to get the bounding box. Below example uses a temp div which is offset -10000px left of the screen, svg is added there and getBBox() returns the value. Remove the element after you get the bbox. It's not an optimal solution but you get the idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var svgstr= '<svg x="0" y="0" width="2200" height="2200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgimportshapes" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">        <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-paper-data="&quot;unlocked&quot;" id="ShapeLayer" fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="none" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal">        <text x="1018.68119" y="511.99246" id="text" fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" font-family="helvetica" font-weight="normal" font-size="18" text-anchor="start">Parterre places debout</text> </svg>'
  
  var svgElement = $(svgstr)
  $("#temp").append(svgElement)
  var bbox = svgElement[0].getBBox() 
  svgElement.remove()
  console.log(bbox)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="temp" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px"></div>
```